# DC current continues measure using shunt resistor with ADS1115 and ESP8266

Tags: arduino, esp8266, shunt

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_ADS1015.h>
Adafruit_ADS1115 ads; /* Use this for the 16-bit version */
void setup(void)
{
Serial.begin(115200);
ads.setGain(GAIN_SIXTEEN); // 16x gain +/- 0.256V 1 bit = 0.125mV 0.0078125mV
ads.begin();
}
void loop(void)
{
int16_t results;
results = ads.readADC_Differential_0_1();
Serial.println(results);
Serial.print("Amps: ");
float amps = ((float)results * 256.0) / 32768.0;//100mv 100A shunt
amps = amps * 2.666; //uncomment for 75mv 200A shunt
Serial.println(amps);
delay(300);
}
```

Is this correct? Because i didn't get real values. I'm using shunt resistor which is 200A 75mV drop. i have esp8266 and ADS1115 to measure the small voltage drop of the shunt.ACS712 hall sensor gives me terrible experience. I'm trying to monitor my solar panel DC current on Blynk App. My plan is to develop DIY smart charging controller which can get maximum efficiency from my panel and get data to a online dashboard.

Comment: A warm welcome to the site. Please note that it's not a free design house, homework-answering service or on-line technical encyclopaedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've already done as much as you possibly could - which yours doesn't remotely show, I'm afraid. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Show your own work and your own findings in considerable detail. The better the quality of your question, the better the quality of the answers it will attract. Again, welcome.

Comment: i'm new to here .I hope i successfully edited the question. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: also post a schematic

Comment: @RANDUNU - Welcome :-) As already commented, please edit the question to add your schematic - otherwise, for example, we don't know whether your choice of calling `ads.readADC_Differential_0_1();` is correct or not. Also, please explain why you chose that function. You said that you "*didn't get real values*". So what values *did* you get, exactly? How are they not "real"? If you disconnect the shunt, what values do you measure? What debugging have you done so far, what results did you get during that debugging & what are your conclusions from those results? Have you done any debugging before?